# How to build a distributed web application platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, distributed, platform

I want to build my own decentralized application platform to build and deploy web applications easily, which is like Google's App Engine, on multiple web servers. What language-independent steps should I take to build such infrastructure?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to build your own? Do you really want the experience?

Comment: I would start by using a number of different existing solutions. Then I would isolate what I like and don't like. And then I would see how they currently implement the features (that I like), along with known issues (limitations I don't like) and any alternatives. It's not a trivial task -- and much more than an SO question can encompass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go check out [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/).  I think it provides an excellent "model" for how you could build your own stack / platform.  The "main" components of the stack are:

- [NGINX](http://nginx.net/): Webserver frontent
- [memcached](http://memcached.org): Memcache service
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com): Task queue
- [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd): Messaging
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org): database

In your own stack you could swap out components quite easily, based on your preferences and needs.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/)? It's open-source and AppEngine compatible.

Comment: I want to build, not to just use.

Comment: @Polat With respect, if you're asking a basic architecture question like this, you probably don't have the expertise to build your own platform yet. Start by learning how platforms like TyphoonAE and AppScale work.

Answer (score 2):

I started using AppScale when i started my  distributed web development journey.It has really helped me understand so my recommendation is to start there.